# Using a Function in a tip Calculator

Tags: vb.net

I have to use a Function for my assignment but im not sure how it should look. This is what I have now... Help write the line the function is declared in vb says its wrong.

```
Dim BillTotal, TipAmount, PerPerson, TipDecimal, Total As Double
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    MsgBox("Tip Amount: " & TipAmount & Chr(13) & "Per Person: " & PerPerson & Chr(13) & "Total: " & Total & Chr(13))

End Sub


Function Total(ByVal BillTotal As Double) As Double
    BillTotal = mtbBill.Text
    TipAmount = (mtbTip.Text / 100) * BillTotal
    TipDecimal = (mtbTip.Text / 100)
    PerPerson = ((BillTotal * (1 + TipDecimal)) / mtbSharedBy.Text)
    Total = BillTotal * (1 + TipDecimal)
End Function
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  Does it work?  Turn on Option Strict.  Always

Comment: "Help write the line the function is declared in vb says its wrong".  That is a nonsensical string of words.  If your IDE is telling you that there's an error and you want help with that, tell us EXACTLY where the error occurs and EXACTLY what the error message is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replaced Chr(13) with vbNewLine - much more readable
2. Added String.Format to better format the text in your MessageBox.
   Making it much more readable
3. Modified your Total function to not accept any parameters since it's return value is just a calculation of values from UI elements

Dim BillTotal, TipAmount, PerPerson, TipDecimal, Total As Double

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


MsgBox(String.Format("Tip Amount: {0}{1} per person{2}{1} Total:{3}{1}", TipAmount, vbNewLine, PerPerson,Total()))
    ' Here I replaced the code with String.Format making it easier to read.
    ' You specify {0}, {1}, {2}, {n} where the number is the order of the parameter.
    ' Then at the end of your string you specify the parameter name such as TipAmount, vbNewLine(which is essentially Chr(13), PerPerson, and Total

End Sub


Function Total() As Double ' Removed the parameter passed into the function as it's not required. 
    BillTotal = mtbBill.Text
    TipAmount = (mtbTip.Text / 100) * BillTotal
    TipDecimal = (mtbTip.Text / 100)
    PerPerson = ((BillTotal * (1 + TipDecimal)) / mtbSharedBy.Text)
    Return( BillTotal * (1 + TipDecimal))
End Function
```

Comment: You need to turn on Option Strict as well

Comment: Option Strict? For what reason?

Comment: It's bad practice to have Option Strict turned off.  All manner of errors can be hidden by having it turned off.